# ServiceStack - Custom CredentialsAuthProvider within .Net MVC app

Tags: servicestack

I am attempting to authenticate against MVC and ServiceStack following the example here - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc. 
My issue is that I am unable to authenticate successfully against ServiceStack on my initial request to Account/LogOn.

ServiceStack related code in LogOn  method of AccountController:

```
var apiAuthService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
apiAuthService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
var apiResponse = apiAuthService.Authenticate(new Auth
                                                    {
                                                        UserName = model.UserName,
                                                        Password = model.Password,
                                                        RememberMe = false
                                                    });
```

I have a custom Authentication Provider that subclasses CredentialsAuthProvider. I Configure as follows in the AppHost class:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
      new ActiveDirectoryAuthProvider(), 
    }));
```

---

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase     authService, string userName, string password)
{
    //class to authenticate against ActiveDirectory        
    var adAuthentication = new ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationService();

    if (!adAuthentication.Authenticate(userName, password))
            return false;

    var session = (CustomUserSession)authService.GetSession(false);
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    session.UserAuthId = session.UserAuthName;
    authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);

    return true;
}
```

I think my issue is that **session.Id** is null at this point and saving the session persists 'urn:iauthsession:' to the 'SessionCache'. However, I'm not sure how to correctly populate **session.Id**. Also, this may or may not be an issue, but the initial LogOn request is to Account/Logon which is handled by MVC. So, there is no request to ServiceStack prior to the AuthService.Authenticate() call in the AccountController.

A possible solution I came up with has been added below in my subclass of CredentialsAuthProvider.

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase     authService, string userName, string password)
{
    //class to authenticate against ActiveDirectory        
    var adAuthentication = new ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationService();

    if (!adAuthentication.Authenticate(userName, password))
            return false;

    var session = (CustomUserSession)authService.GetSession(false);

    //A possible solution???
    if(session.Id == null)
    {
        var req = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
        var sessId = HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse().CreateSessionIds(req);
        session.Id = sessId;
        req.SetItem(SessionFeature.SessionId, sessId);
    }
    //end possible solution
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    session.UserAuthId = session.UserAuthName;
    authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);

    return true;
}
```

Is there a configuration or call I'm missing to 'wire up' ServiceStack Authentication within MVC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I am doing in my TryAuthenticate is validating the user name, password and returning true if valid.

I have another override method called OnAuthenticated where I am saving the session information.  OnAuthenticated passes the Auth Service and the Session as parameter so you only have to:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session,.....
{
  session.IsAuthenticated = true;
  session.....
  authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
}
```

This seems to store my session information as long as I registered the ICacheClient.